# Authenticate user in google Assistant using actions sdk

Tags: android, actions-on-google

As per the google actions sdk documentation here https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking

I have followed all the steps of Enable Account Linking.
When the any intent is called I am checking the user is signed in or not by

```
let accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;
  if ('' + accessToken === 'undefined') {
   console.log('Inside not logged In');
    app.askForSignIn();
 }
```

and which sends the response as

```
 {
"conversationToken": "{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}",
"expectUserResponse": true,
"expectedInputs": [
    {
        "inputPrompt": {
            "initialPrompts": [
                {
                    "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_SIGN_IN"
                }
            ],
            "noInputPrompts": []
        },
        "possibleIntents": [
            {
                "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
                "inputValueData": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

which should invoke authentication flow at the device.
Though the google assistant is saying as below.

```
{
"response": "test application isn’t responding right now. Try again soon.\n",
"conversationToken": "GhBzaW11bGF0b3JfZGV2aWNl",
"audioResponse": "//NExAASW...",
"debugInfo": {},
"visualResponse": {}
}
```

I have tried all the things given in documentation.
Could you please help how to implement log in functionality using Actions SDK and not API.AI in google assistant?

Below is the response from API.AI to google assistant to invoke authentication flow which is working.

here is the response which was generated by API.AI to invoke user authentication.

```
{
"response": "It looks like your test app account is not linked yet",
"conversationToken": "GhBzaW11bGF0b3JfZDV2aWNl",
"audioResponse": "//NExAAQ+...",
"debugInfo": {
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
        {
            "name": "Account Linking Url",
            "debugInfo": "https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=pathway-171404_dev&scopes=test&return_url=https://www.google.com/"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Is there any way we can generate this response in Actions SDK in node.js file?

Actions.json file:

```
{
 "actions": [
   {
     "description": "Launch intent",
     "name": "MAIN",
     "fulfillment": {
       "conversationName": "mainConversation"
     },
     "intent": {
       "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
     }
   },
   {
     "description": "Sign In intent",
     "name": "SIGN_IN",
     "fulfillment": {
       "conversationName": "mainConversation"
     },
     "intent": {
       "name": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN"
     }
   }
 ],
 "conversations": {
   "mainConversation": {
     "name": "mainConversation",
     "url": "https://4541d296.ngrok.io/pathway-171404/us-central1/conversationComponent",
     "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - this is using the Actions on Google API, correct? (You're not building your own device and adding the Assistant to it?) Have you confirmed your app is being called and isn't returning an error?

Comment: Yup, It's Actions on Google API (I am making app in google assistant app using actions sdk and I am not building my own device). App is being called on Main intent is fired and I am checking for signed in or not and sending the response as app.askForSignIn(); which I have mentioned in question with the actual json response which is being sent but google actions console is showing as "application isn’t responding right now. Try again soon".

Comment: Can you also post your actions.json file?

Comment: Have you also gotten some responses working without the account linking part?

Comment: Yup, I got normal response,Basic Card,List Selector,etc working @Prisoner

Comment: Can you add your actions.json file to your question, please. (Replacing sensitive information with placeholders.)

Comment: Sure, I have added Actions.json file in question.